# HTTP requests from React not reaching Node.js backend on production server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, nginx, server, proxy

I'm trying to get my front end requests to communicate with my backend on my server.
Just a temporary implementation at the moment to get it working.

It works fine on my machine since i'm using proxy inside my react, but something is wrong in the server configurations.

Maybe it's something with my code I'm not sure so I'll include some snippets just in case.

An example of my request structure
Front-end React

```
export default function SinglePost() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/posts');
        setPosts(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching posts:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

My Package.json If it's relevant to the issue

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env PORT=3006 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5500",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
  }
```

Back-End

```
Part of my postsTest.js file

app.get('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
    const singlePostId = req.query.postId;

    if (singlePostId) {
      const matchPost = posts.find((post) => post.id === singlePostId);
      if (matchPost){
        res.json(matchPost);
      } else {
        res.status(404).json({message: 'Post Not Found'});
      }
    } else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });

Part of my server.js file

const express = require('express');
const adminPosts = require('./postsTest'); 
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const PORT = 5500;


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

adminPosts.setup(app);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started, port is ${PORT}`);
});
```

Snippet of my backend Package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/server",
    "dev": "nodemon src/server"
  },
```

How I setup my front-end to run

```
ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
react-node-app.nginx

server {
        listen 81;
        server_name 111.11.111.11; #Just put a filler IP address (not my actual ip)

        root /home/bob/webname/webnames/client/build;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5500/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

How I setUp service to run

```
[Unit]
Description=Node BackEnd
After=network.target

[Service]
User=bob
WorkingDirectory=/home/bob/blogwebsite/BlogWebsite/server/src
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node server.js --port=5500 --host=127.0.0.1
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


sudo systemctl status react-node-app.service
● react-node-app.service - Node BackEnd
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/react-node-app.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-03-14 03:32:34 UTC; 51min ago
   Main PID: 1912 (node)
      Tasks: 11 (limit: 1116)
     Memory: 18.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/react-node-app.service
             └─1912 /usr/bin/node server.js --port=5500 --host=127.0.0.1

Mar 14 03:32:34 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-tor1-01 systemd[1]: Started Node BackEnd.
Mar 14 03:32:35 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-tor1-01 node[1912]: Server started on port port is 5500
Mar 14 04:01:25 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-tor1-01 node[1912]: testing receiving data backend
```

Ran the curl command to see if the backend was even running properly and it seems fine

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/api/posts
[{"title":"dasdas","description":"dsadasda",etc...
```

The Front End and Backend are running I guess, but this is the error I get

```
sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/nginx/access.log
 "GET /api/posts HTTP/1.1" 404 145 "http://111.11.111.11:81/"

and in browser

GET
http://111.11.111.11:81/api/posts
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 31ms]

Error fetching posts:
```

If you have any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it, from what i gathered it seems like the proxy is just not working.

I am expecting my front-end request to receive the information from my backend via the proxy I set up.

Comment: Figured out a way to get it working, still not fully sure why but I switched out
proxy_pass http://localhost:5500/;
for
proxy_pass http://111.11.111.11:5500;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason you're using port 5500 on the back end? This should ideally be 443 for https connections or 80 for http connections.

Comment: Just a random port I picked to run it on, I initially thought there would be conflicts since I have my other website rerouted and running on port 443. But you are correct, since my website is in a different server block and the other one has a domain name it won't conflict. I switched back to port 80 for now, while I'm still testing and don't have an SSL setup for that website.

Comment: yep, just switched from localhost:5500 to proxy_pass 111.11.111.11:5500;